# Método que crie uma nova lista com base em elementos de uma lista existente?

Tags: java, c#

Em c# existe a função `numeros.GetRange(0, quant);`

Gostaria de saber qual o função equivalente ao  `numeros.GetRange(0, quant);` do C# em Java

Comment: O que é `numeros`? Uma `List`?

Comment: @jbueno sim é `ArrayLis numeros =  new ArrayLis();`

Comment: Você poderia melhorar sua pergunta. Ao invés de procurar por uma "tradução" de `GetRange`, pedir uma função que crie uma nova lista com base em elementos de uma lista existente. (Só para pontuar, o negativo não foi meu, eu acho que essa é uma boa pergunta, só não foi bem elaborada).

Comment: @jbueno agora você falando eu entendi essa função, pois eu não sabia

Comment: Perfeito, bom ter te ajudado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para pegar um pedaço de uma lista e colocar em outra, pode-se usar o [`subList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

Você deve passar como parâmetro o index inicial (será incluso na nova lista) e o final (não será incluso na nova lista);

Ex.:

```
ArrayList<Integer> novaLista = numeros.subList(0, indexFinal);
```